# 3d print add_ "zero Faces" on default cube on all faces

Tags: 3d-printing

Anyone know why the default cube is showing "Zero Faces" on the entire cube in the 3d print add on. Collapse by distance does not fix it.

This is just a test and I can export it and fix it in Netfabb, but this happens with many of my models having all zero faces and I can't figure out why I can **only** fix it in Netfabb. Collapse by distance in Blender always changes my model too much.

Is there a better way in blender to approach Zero faces? or is it only collapse by distance? Just checking with you guys before I spend loads of time exporting models.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure exactly what 'Zero Faces means on that addon, but if there's a 0 (zero) against its entry, it means that there aren't any 'Zero Faces', so all is ok. If you did get a non-zero value, you could go into Edit mode with Face select enabled, click on the Zero Faces line on the addon and the dud faces should be hilighted.

Comment: Yes Thanks, it says all 6 faces. Just trying to see if there is a better workflow than merging by distance to fix em. Or better yet a way to prevent them in the first place?

Comment: The default cube shows '0' for every entry here except 'Overhang Face' which shows 1. Clicking that entry hilights the face on the bottom of the cube. I can't see why merging by distance would have any effect whatsoever on a default cube.

Comment: Thanks John, I just realized why the cube had all faces showing Zero faces. The cube was scaled down to a small scale. Tried to change the degenerate settings with no luck though. So really unsure how to fix it in the end...

Comment: What do you mean by "scaled down to a small size" and had you then applied the scale in Object mode (Ctrl-A > Scale)?  Also, what do you mean by "degenerate settings"?

Comment: I scaled the cube down to 5mm and yes, applied the scale. Then pressed degenerate. the results then are zero for all 6 faces. Next to degenerate are numbers which I would think change the scale to which it gauges the results. (default is .0001) I added some zeros and took away some with no difference in the result. Wait, I just added one more zero (7 in all ) and it has no zero faces! yay.

Comment: Not really sure what the point is of doing this if you can just change the setting?

Comment: No idea. Sounds like a possible precision problem. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/3d_print_toolbox.html#checks) is the section about the checks in the Blender manual.

Comment: OK Thanks for the reference